# Tensorflow 2.3: How to parallelize reading text from big file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, bigdata

I need to break down my data-set file of size 4GB into chunks small chunks. As part of optimizing the time consumption, I would like to maximize the parallel processing. Currently, I can observe that cores of CPU and GPU are under utilized. See the attached output in the image [here](https://14285133167676990789.googlegroups.com/attach/c071981ecb8c/Screenshot%20from%202020-08-25%2015-01-32.png?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrFTRnQ114WIjkRdTT93aL65l9Mp34Mb6i4ZbGQmLT5iUY3Md_QRSmpP1myWcU5l_reVh-94UQ88HLxP-GvxQh99HudT2ZalvpT5TGxzbT3XpU8L-bo).

My Code snippet looks like below

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
    """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
    if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
        value = value.numpy() # BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _float_feature(value):
    """Returns a float_list from a float / double."""
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
    """Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint."""
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def serialize_row(text, rating):
    # Create a dictionary mapping the feature name to the tf.Example-compatible data type.
    feature = {
        'text': _bytes_feature(text),
        'rating': _float_feature(rating),
    }

    # Create a Features message using tf.train.Example.
    example_proto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    return example_proto.SerializeToString()

def transform(example):
    str_example = example.decode("utf-8")
    json_example = json.loads(str_example)
    overall = json_example.get('overall', -99)
    text = json_example.get('reviewText', '')
    if type(text) is str:
        text = bytes(text, 'utf-8')
    tf_serialized_string = serialize_row(text, overall)
    return tf_serialized_string 


line_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames=[file_path])
line_dataset = line_dataset.map(lambda row: tf.numpy_function(transform, [row], tf.string))
line_dataset = line_dataset.shuffle(2)
line_dataset = line_dataset.batch(NUM_OF_RECORDS_PER_BATCH_FILE)
'''
    Perform batchwise transformation of the population.
'''
start = time.time()
for idx, line in line_dataset.enumerate():
    FILE_NAMES = 'test{0}.tfrecord'.format(idx)
    end = time.time()
    time_taken = end - start
    tf.print('Processing for file - {0}'.format(FILE_NAMES))
    DIRECTORY_URL = '/home/gaurav.gupta/projects/practice/'
    filepath = os.path.join(DIRECTORY_URL, 'data-set', 'electronics', FILE_NAMES)
    batch_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(line)
    writer = tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter(filepath)
    writer.write(batch_ds)
    tf.print('Processing for file - {0} took {1}'.format(FILE_NAMES, time_taken))
tf.print('Done')
```

Logs to showcase execution flow

```
Processing for file - test0.tfrecord took 14.350863218307495
Processing for file - test1.tfrecord took 12.695453882217407
Processing for file - test2.tfrecord took 12.904462575912476
Processing for file - test3.tfrecord took 12.344425439834595
Processing for file - test4.tfrecord took 11.188365697860718
Processing for file - test5.tfrecord took 11.319620609283447
Processing for file - test6.tfrecord took 11.285977840423584
Processing for file - test7.tfrecord took 11.169529438018799
Processing for file - test8.tfrecord took 11.289997816085815
Processing for file - test9.tfrecord took 11.431073188781738
Processing for file - test10.tfrecord took 11.428141593933105
Processing for file - test11.tfrecord took 3.223125457763672
Done
```

I have tried `num_parallel_reads` argument but couldn't see much difference. I believe it can be handy while reading multiple files instead of single big file.

I am seeking for your suggestion to parallelize this task to reduce the time consumption.

Comment: I would try passing the argument num_parallel_calls to the map call. Viz https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TextLineDataset#map

Comment: @VladimírKunc Didn't helped much. I measure the amount of time time taken per enumeration and without num_parallel_calls in map avg time was nearly 13 sec, and with num_parallel_calls in map it is nearly 12 sec.

Comment: It is hard to say what is the bottleneck just from the code - maybe measure times of individual parts of the code? Maybe the enumeration of the line dataset and the following processing is slow? If that would be the case, I would try to parallelize that part - it seems that there is no reason to have it sequential. I would put the code into a single function and then use https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html to call that parallelly on the dataset enumeration.

Comment: @VladimírKunc That's what I want to do. I want to run the each loop in parallel. Each loop is responsible for executing for a batch and these batch can be executed in parallel. I would like to understand the provision to make them execute in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this (I like to use [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) as it is quite simple to put into existing code, you could probably do something similar with many other frameworks, furthermore, joblib does not use GPU nor it does not use any JITting):

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from tqdm import tqdm
...

def process_file(idx, line):
  FILE_NAMES = 'test{0}.tfrecord'.format(idx)
  end = time.time()
  time_taken = end - start
  tf.print('Processing for file - {0}'.format(FILE_NAMES))
  DIRECTORY_URL = '/home/gaurav.gupta/projects/practice/'
  filepath = os.path.join(DIRECTORY_URL, 'data-set', 'electronics', FILE_NAMES)
  batch_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(line)
  writer = tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter(filepath)
  writer.write(batch_ds)
  #tf.print('Processing for file - {0} took {1}'.format(FILE_NAMES, time_taken))
  return FILE_NAMES, time_taken


times = Parallel(n_jobs=12, prefer="processes")(delayed(process_file)(idx, line) for idx, line in tqdm(line_dataset.enumerate(), total=len(line_dataset)))
print('Done.')
```

This is untested code and I am also unsure how it will work with the tf code, but I would give it a try.

The `tqdm` is totally unnecessary, it is just something I prefer to use as it provides a nice progress bar.

Comment: Thanks for putting your efforts.

I believe this is bit hacky way to achieve parallelization. There should be something within the tensorflow as this seems to be a natural requirement.

Thanks for suggestiing `joblib` module.